# Open another app within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am creating an app to run multiple tasks within a same activity. I am achieving this using fragments. Now, I want to run a game which is installed on my phone in a fragment within my activity.

I tried this  :

```
PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.exo.drive");
getActivity().startActivityFromFragment(this, intent, getTargetRequestCode());
```

But this as expected opens another activity and launches the game. How do I make the game run within my fragment?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You can only add or replace the contents of a fragment container with a fragment, and even then, you can't take another installed app's fragment and add it to your view.

Comment: Thanks Josephus for the reply. Is there any way I can launch another app within my same activity , if not for fragments? It has to start another activity is it?