# Open another application inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Open another app within a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373862/open-another-app-within-a-fragment)

I'm creating an application with a single activity with a `SlidingTabsLayout` and every tab is a fragment. Is there a way to open an installed application and just run it as it is inside one of the tabs? The other application is just a single activity which I want to display in my tab as it is. The answer in the question above said I can't do it, but maybe in the 1.5 years that passed since the question was asked, something has changed?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to open an installed application and just run it as it is inside one of the tabs

No.

> The answer is the question above said I can't do it

The answer is correct.